# Run the most recent call of the function

Tags: godot

Here's the code:

```
extends ColorRect

onready var label = $Label
onready var colorRect = self

var textPiece = ''

func text(value):
    colorRect.visible = true
    textPiece = ''
    for i in range(len(value)):
        textPiece += value[i]
        label.text = textPiece
        yield(get_tree().create_timer(0.05), "timeout")
    yield(get_tree().create_timer(5.0), "timeout")
    colorRect.visible = false


func _ready():
    colorRect.visible = false
```

I want to be able to use the function `text('test')` but then use `text('anothertext')` AGAIN, and cancel out the other function.

Basically, I expect the text function to run text('test'), but if I use the function again when it's still running text('test'), I want it to run the most recent call instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the issue is that you are creating and dispatching timeouts.

To do this, you would want a couple things:

- A single ticking timer. Which will call a method on a fixed interval.
- Store the text you actually want to put.

The method would add a character from the text each time (you can use the length of `Label.text` to figure out where you are on it).

*However, just don't do it that way.*

---

Since this kind of text animation is common in games, Godot `Label` has a `visible_characters` property.

So you can change the `Label.text` and animate `Label.visible_characters`.

Furthermore a good way to do that animation is with a tween. I'll be using the new tween API (Godot 3.5+) here.

```
func text(value:String) -> void:
    label.text = value
    label.visible_characters = 0
    var tween := get_tree().create_tween()
    tween.tween_property(label, "visible_characters", len(value), 0.05 * len(value))
```

Here `tween_property` will change the value of a property (`visible_characters`) from the value it had when you called it (`0`) to the value we specify (`len(value)`), and it will do so increasingly during the specified time duration (`0.05 * len(value)`).

---

We can go ahead and use the same `tween` to wait and hide the `ColorRect`:

```
func text(value:String) -> void:
    colorRect.visible = true
    label.text = value
    label.visible_characters = 0
    var tween := get_tree().create_tween()
    tween.tween_property(label, "visible_characters", len(value), 0.05 * len(value))
    tween.tween_interval(5.0)
    tween.tween_callback(colorRect, "hide")
```

---

And since we don't want the previous one to continue running, we will store a reference to it, so we can stop it when we want to start a new one:

```
var tween:SceneTreeTween

func text(value:String) -> void:
    if tween != null:
        tween.stop()

    colorRect.visible = true
    label.text = value
    label.visible_characters = 0
    tween = get_tree().create_tween()
    tween.tween_property(label, "visible_characters", len(value), 0.05 * len(value))
    tween.tween_interval(5.0)
    tween.tween_callback(colorRect, "hide")
```